# Extend Identity Provider URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I just have a question regarding to Identity Provider URL.Is it possible if i would like to modify|custom|extend the Identity Provider URL? (localhost:9443/samlsso)

I currently run two SSO (SAML2) enabled apps on my local tomcat on localhost and name app1 and app2. The behavior of the applications is to redirect to login panel when the user is trying to access the applications. Since it is SSO enabled, it redirect to WSO2IS login panel. If both application are not logged in and redirected to the SSO login page of WSO2IS. The first one to login works successfully. Because the first one already logged, the second one doesn't need to be sign on again. But i would like to make the second one must be sign on again because there are 2 different issue name and i intend to use the issue name for the filter or condition

I am using WSO2 identity server 4.6.0

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is bit unclear to me. Is it that you don't want SSO between webapps, but only between webapp and IDP? Then it seems, it's not complete SAML SSO scenario.

Still for the filtering, you may be able to write a 'custom authenticator', implementing the interface 'org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.CarbonServerAuthenticator' and engage it in the flow.

Comment: Hello Pushpalanka, thank for your suggestion, it actually not complete SAML SSO scenario, so i decide to change new way, using password grant type